# JSONSerialisation API different url not working

Tags: json, swift, weather-api, openweathermap, app-transport-security

I am trying to create a basic weather app, but now I face problems with initialising my personal api in my app. The problem likely lies in the URL as it works if I change it. However, the current api I have is the sole on that works for my country's weather.

*P.S. the other url that works is from an online course I'm following*

This is the one that doesn't work

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>**nea.gov.sg**</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Meanwhile, this works

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>**openweathermap.org**</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

So then is it due to the additional domain of **nea.gov.sg** as compared to **openweathermap.org**? So to answer some questions, both are **http://** and I tried to print out both api but only the url for openweathermap.org works with both the **same code**.

Here's the API call code I used

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=*[keyCode]*")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    print(jsonResult)

                } catch {
                    print("JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: are both urls http or is one https? Also what do you mean when you say "it doesn't work" are you getting an error?

Comment: when I print out the api, only the one for openweather.org works, when both codes are exactly the same, only this source code for the info.plist is different

Comment: could you add your api call code here as well?

Comment: This link may help you: https://www.nea.gov.sg/docs/default-source/api/developer%27s-guide.pdf. Have you followed steps outlined here?

Comment: @PranavKasetti yes I did, I checked it out too, and yea ill put the api call code on top

Comment: please show the error from the app console.  Also, why the asterisks?  The includes subdomains will handle the apl. prefix, so your exception domain should just be `<key>nea.gov.sg</key>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing this instead to your plist?

```
<key>**api.nea.gov.sg**</key>
```

Comment: nope doesn't work too :/, I think its the additional dots in the website name. >the " nea.gov " part

Comment: there's no error message, it prints out "JSON Processing Failed" which is part of the Do Catch function

Comment: can you replace your `try` statement with `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]`